# API post request with php to azure deployed model

Tags: php, azure, api, post

We have created and deployed a model in Azure ML, which can be accessed by a api. Since we would like to display the output of the api on a Wordpress website, the api call should be made within a php script. My php script is working, but it does not shows any output but 'data', where I expect a JSON output. Do I need to specify a output.php file for example where my output will be send to or something?

We followed the documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service and were able to make an API call in Python. Unfortunately, this was not as easy in php, especially since I have no php programming experience at all. I feel like the API is working, since some response is given, but not the expected result.

I have written the following code:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$url = 'http://<unique-api-address>.westeurope.azurecontainer.io/score';

//our model needs 21 input variables
$data_json = '{ "data:" :
  [
      [ 21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ]
  ]
 }';

//print_r($data_json);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',));

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output === FALSE) {
  echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

// $response = json_decode($output, true);
// $errors = $response['response']['errors'];
// $data = $response['response']['data'][0];

print_r($output);
 ?>
```

I expected the output to be a JSON file, but my output is only the word 'data'

Comment: Do not create your own json. Create an array, then use `json_encode` to make sure it's encoded properly.

Comment: Thanks you so much @aynber ! It works! I used the following code:
`$data_array = new \stdClass();
$data_array->data = array(array( 21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1));
$data_json = json_encode($data_array,true);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have figured it out by yourself.

Here I just want to show you another solution. As php supports string as an index in an array, and the string index will be encoded as key by json_encode function, the following code will work too:

```
$post_data = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
    )
);

echo json_encode($post_data);
```

The output:

```
{"data":[[21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]}
```